# TypeError in Jython?

Tags: java, python, jython, typeerror, jes

I'm trying to make two lines across a circle, like an X. Since it's an X, to find the `(x,y)` I just multiplied sqrt(2)/2 by the radius and then added or subtracted it from the `(x,y)` origin depending on what corner of the circle it was in. However I keep getting a TypeError 'The error was: 2nd arg can't be coerced to int' This is what I have:

```
#starting/ending points of the line
a1 = z - ((sqrt(2) / 2)*(r1))
b1 = w - ((sqrt(2) / 2)*(r1))
a2 = z + ((sqrt(2) / 2)*(r1))
b2 = w + ((sqrt(2) / 2)*(r1))
c1 = z - ((sqrt(2) / 2)*(r1))
d1 = w + ((sqrt(2) / 2)*(r1))
c2 = z + ((sqrt(2) / 2)*(r1))
d2 = w - ((sqrt(2) / 2)*(r1))
pic.addLine(black, a1, b1, a2, b2)
pic.addLine(black, c1, d1, c2, d2)
```

...where *z* is the x origin, *w* is the y origin, and *r1* is the radius.
What am I doing wrong here? This what I'm getting :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried turning the `a1`, `b1`, `a2`, `b2`, etc. arguments to integer yet? `int(a1), int(b1), int(a2), int(b2)`?

Comment: What gets displayed if you do `print type(a1)` right before you call `pic.addLine`?

Answer (score 2):

By using `sqrt()` you end up with floating point values, but the method you are calling wants integers only. Call `int()` on the values before passing them to `pic.addLine()`:

```
pic.addLine(black, int(a1), int(b1), int(a2), int(b2))
pic.addLine(black, int(c1), int(d1), int(c2), int(d2))
```